# how to get value of wp_dropdown_categories

Tags: dropdown, categories

I am making a widget and I have used the [wp_dropdown_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories) function in that widget. What I can't figure out is how to get the selected value from the dropdown.

What variable is the selected stored in?

```
$args = array('show_option_none' => 'No Category','hide_empty' => 0);
wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the value? As in HTML the selected value is available as `selected` within the `option`

Comment: I want to make a category loop based on the chosen category

Comment: Maybe you're better of using [get_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) to loop through an array of categories instead :)

Comment: Your 100th question :)

Comment: can you post a code snippet to show what you mean Sven ? I have not been able to get this working

Comment: Peter, this is in no way a duplicate of that question. I do not even have a loop yet in my code. the correct answer to this question is not even close to what was posted in that other question. I have found the answer to this question and will post it when I get all the code working. I am not using get_tags or get_categories at all at this stage. All I needed to do to get the values was add some options to the wp_dropdown_categories function. then I could do a print_r($instance) and see that my values are there. I could also find them in the database. So now I know how to get the values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can get the categories via [get_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) function (which will get the same categories as [wp_dropdown_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories) function), but as array and without the markup.

As the value is **returned** as array, we can loop through the categories and generate the HTML ourself.

Usually, we would aim for a structure like this:

```
<select name="categories">
  <option value="1">Category 1</option>
  <option value="2">Category 2</option>
  <option value="3">Category 3</option>
</select>
```

So we're going to generate the structure from above via PHP by looping through the `$categories` array:

```
echo '<select name="categories">';

  // Get categories as array
  $categories = get_categories( $args );
  foreach ( $categories as $category ) :

    echo '<option value="' . $category->term_id . '">' . $category->name . '</option>';

  endforeach;

echo '</select>';
```

Feel free to modify the function via the `$args` parameters (see [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories#Examples) for reference).

Now we'll just need to add the `selected` attribute within the `<option>`, so we're going to add this via a short if statement to compare the current `$category->term_id` and the one saved in the database `$stored_category_id`:

```
$stored_category_id = 10; // This is the value from the database
$selected = ( $stored_category_id == $category->term_id  ) ? 'selected' : '';
```

And that's it! Your complete snippet (maybe with a default option at the beginning) should now look something like this:

```
echo '<select name="categories">';
  // Add custom option as default
  echo '<option>' . __('No Category', 'text-domain') . '</option>';

  // Get categories as array
  $categories = get_categories( $args );
  foreach ( $categories as $category ) :

    // Check if current term ID is equal to term ID stored in database
    $selected = ( $stored_category_id ==  $category->term_id  ) ? 'selected' : '';

    echo '<option value="' . $category->term_id . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $category->name . '</option>';

  endforeach;

echo '</select>';
```

Good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks Sven, My main issue what I wasn't sure how to write up the select in php while getting the values from the database. What really surprises me is the lack of information in the codex.